# Github post hook to DEVELOPMENT VM

Tags: linux, git, apache, github, virtual-machine

**Overview**

I have 2 servers, One server is local and other is hosted off site.

1 - Production

1 - Development

The Production is hosted and has an outside IP to be accessed from anyone on the web.

The Development can only be accessed internally ( No outside IP ).

They both use the same URL www.blah.com and our developers manage to switch between the two sites by editing their windows hosts file to point to the correct server.

**The Problem**

How would I update the development server though Github on a push with a hook becuase there is no internet URL?  I suppose I could create a CRON but I would love to use a hook somehow to only update when a push happens.  Production has a URL so I can use Github to do a post hook to update.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

1. When PROD is pushed to, you want to update DEV
2. PROD cannot access DEV

In this case you PROD cannot update DEV directly. If there is another site MIDDLE that PROD can access, and MIDDLE can access DEV, then you could setup a chain of triggers from PROD -> MIDDLE -> DEV. Otherwise the only way is a cron job on DEV, polling periodically.

If PROD could access DEV directly then you could setup a web hook, which could trigger a script on DEV, which could perform a pull from PROD. This is a common practice.

Comment: I am going to have 2 branches 1 DEV & 1 PROD and they are separate,  DEV will always be ahead of PROD.  The programmer will be merging to DEV first to test changes. Once it completes its tests there then they will merge that branch to PROD.  Also if I use the idea of dev.blah.com wouldn't I have to update all my URLS on dev?